# python list reverse and sort from second element

Tags: python, list, sorting, reverse

I want to transform a list like this:

```
[[x, [1,2,3]], [y, [2,3,4]], [z, 4]]
```

to become:

```
[[1, x], [2, [x,y]], [3, [x,y]], [4, z]]
```

... essentially turning it "inside-out", so that the numbers in the innermost lists are separated out, and the letters associated with them collected into lists for each number.

How can I do that?

Comment: For me, it is absolutely incomprehensible, how you got the second list from the first one. On the second look: Are there 3 lists on the first line and 3 lists on the second, on one list on each?

Comment: I think the last items in your "before" and "after" lists should actually be `[z, [4]]` and `[4, [y,z]]`, for your question to make sense ...

Comment: @Jessica I've substantially rewritten your question so that it's easier to understand. If I misinterpreted what you actually want, please speak up.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this fairly straightforwardly using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [['x', [1, 2, 3]], ['y', [2, 3, 4]], ['z', [4]]]

temp = defaultdict(list)

for k, s in data:
    for v in s:
        temp[v].append(k)

result = sorted(temp.items())
# [(1, ['x']), (2, ['x', 'y']), (3, ['x', 'y']), (4, ['y', 'z'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> d=defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in l:
...       if isinstance(v,list):
...             for t in v:
...                    d[t].append(k)
...       else:
...                    d[v].append(k)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: ['x'], 2: ['x', 'y'], 3: ['x', 'y'], 4: ['y', 'z']})
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an incomprehensible list comprehension:

```
in_list = ['x', [1, 2, 3]], ['y', [2, 3, 4]], ['z', [4]]
[[num, [sublist[0] for sublist in in_list if num in sublist[1]]] for num in sorted(list(set(num for sublist in in_list for num in sublist[1])))]
```

Gives:

```
Out[218]: [[1, ['x']], [2, ['x', 'y']], [3, ['x', 'y']], [4, ['y', 'z']]]
```